# How does Jaynes's principle of transformation groups work?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, bayesian

(Wikipedia page for background info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_transformation_groups )

---

I'm reading Edwin Jaynes's paper, "Prior Probabilities":

http://bayes.wustl.edu/etj/articles/prior.pdf

and on page 17 he describes the principle of transformation groups, wherein he provides a method to derive objective prior distributions for different parameters of a given probability density function.

Trouble is, I don't get how it works.

Jaynes seems to be trying to find a change of variables for a pdf such that the new pdf, multiplied by the Jacobian determinant of the new parameterization, results in the exact same pdf as before the transformation. Then, he tries to find a prior distribution for a given set of parameters such that the prior distribution, when run through the same change of variables and multiplied by the same Jacobian determinant, remains the same.

His notation is a little vague, so here's my interpretation of one of his examples. Let's say you have a reparameterization of $\frac{1}{\sigma}f(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})dx$, denoted $\Phi$, where $\Phi(x,\mu, \sigma)=(a(x+b),a(\mu+b),a\sigma)$, where $a$ and $b$ are arbitrary values.. Plugging these new variables into $\frac{1}{\sigma}f(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})dx$, we have $\frac{1}{a\sigma}f(\frac{a(x+b)-a(\mu+b)}{a\sigma})dx'\mathbf{J_{\Phi}}$, which simplifies to:

$\frac{1}{a\sigma}f(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})dx'
\left| \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & a & 0 \\
0 & 0 & a \end{array}
\right) \right|
=
\frac{a^{2}}{\sigma}f(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})dx'
$

... which isn't the same as the original, though Jaynes says that it is. He then proceeds to take the Jacobian and apply it to a prior, which I also don't understand how he's able to do. Aren't Jacobian determinants supposed to multidimensional versions of the coefficient of $du$ in $u$ substitution? Why is Jaynes able to multiply one seemingly unrelated function by the Jacobian determinant of another?

I'm positive I've done something wrong with my calculations, or made a fumble in my reasoning somewhere. If anyone could run me through how this method works, I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

He's applying the Jacobian to do a [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables). When you do a change of variables you distort the total mass assigned to all of the subsets of the support. The Jacobian [adjusts the integrand appropriately to provide the same mass over the original domain of integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables).

In general, if you have a probability density $f_X(x)$ and you do a change of variables to $x\rightarrow y$ where $y = g(x)$ then $f_Y(y) = |\frac{d}{dx}g^{-1}(x)|f(g^{-1}(x))$.

He uses this, using his notation now, and works under the assumption that $h(x) = h(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})$ for some location and scale parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$. He then just comes up with a clever transformation of variables:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\mu' &= \mu +b\\
\sigma'  &= a\sigma\\
x' &= a(x-\mu)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

The Jacobian of this transform is $|J|=a^{-1}$. Because:
\begin{equation}
h(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})\frac{1}{\sigma} = h(\frac{\frac{x'-\mu'}{a}}{\frac{\sigma'}{a}})\frac{a}{\sigma'}|J| = h(\frac{\frac{x'-\mu'}{a}}{\frac{\sigma'}{a}})\frac{aa^{-1}}{\sigma'}
\end{equation}

all of the $a$'s cancel out and we get the original equation in terms of the new variables.

Doing the change of variables on a prior distribution $f(\mu,\sigma)$ gives us $f(\mu,\sigma)\rightarrow af(\mu',\sigma') = af(\mu+b,a\sigma) $, which he calls $g(\mu',\sigma')$.

Under our assumption, shifts and scales of the parameters do not change the prior probabilities, so we need to find $f(\mu,\sigma)$ such that $f(\mu,\sigma) = af(\mu+b,a\sigma)$ almost surely with respect to Lebesgue measure.

This is satisfied by $f(\mu,\sigma) \propto \frac{1}{\sigma}$, which can be easily checked by plugging in $af(\mu+b,a\sigma) = \frac{a}{a\sigma} = \frac{1}{\sigma}$